# Socratic Discussion

Tags: discussion

Seeing how I do not have the reputation points to ask this on meta.  Would this site be eligible to have a Socratic Discussion?  I have been looking through the purpose of this site, and found that this is not covered by the three, unless Socratic Discussion are too long, and have many answers.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the SE model, Socratic dialectic is unfortunately infeasible. The Socratic process involves a great deal of back-and-forth exchange and dialogue, and a successful Socratic interaction will be long, bidirectional, and highly interactive. The SE model only provides for question-answer arrangements where a person asks *one* question and gets *one* answer, with a minimal amount of discussion between the two (if discussion is necessary, that's the sign of an unclear question or answer). So the *process* necessary to a Socratic conversation has no place to fit in.

You may have luck in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium), however.